# If I use ajax to add new elements to the dom, how do I use a url query string to do the same?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a project written in php and javascript that allows users to 'crud' images. I use the mvc pattern with index.php being the controller that takes the actions submitted via ajax, and returns the relevant data in a json string.

I am trying to create usable links by placing the query in the url, but I'm not sure of the correct approach. 
Until this point every request was made by ajax post, so ajax handled the response which includes creating new elements, updating the layout etc.

If I add ?action=foo to the end of the url I only get the json string as the controller renders everything for the initial page load(javascript resources etc), then simply returns json strings based on subsequent ajax requests. I tried also including the view/home.php with the relevant action code, but this just displays the home page with the json string hidden underneath and this approach will not work when using ajax.

Since the home page is only rendered on the initial page load, putting the action in the url skips the home page and the page reloads with only the json string. Should I add a test condition to check if query was not sent by ajax? If I then reload the home page with the json how do I get the correct js function to handle the json? Or do I need to completely rethink how I structured my code?

```
switch ($action) {
        case "home":
    case NULL:
        include_once('view/home.php'); //this includes all relevant js resources on page load
        break;
    case "search":
//retrieve requested data from db then-
header('Content-Type: application/json');
            echo json_encode($foo);
            break;
}
```

**New elements are added to the dom via javascript functions after the user makes a request using ajax. I'm trying to figure out how to repeat this functionality using a query string in the browser url. What am I missing?**

Comment: It's not a trivial question.  You can a) have your php code render the required "search results" into the html (duplicating the javascript), or b) trigger the javascript to perform a search once the empty home.php is loaded, or c) do the whole thing in javascript (reading the parameter from the url and calling the search function)

Comment: Thanks for your comment James. I like suggestion c), I searched how to prevent page reloading on url change but I didn't find what I was looking for. I tried adding listener on window location change then preventing default but obviously that didn't work. Is it possible to prevent reload?
  I'm sure I could figure out a solution using b), as far as a) I'm not sure if you mean sending js inline(never done b4) from php, or creating the html template in php.

Comment: Page will reload on url change (except for `#` hash) so you have to take that into account.  Having a hard link to something implies you want it to load the page from scratch otherwise use your ajax stuff.  And yes option A is to build the html in php and insert it into the correct place in the page (so you would have javascript code somewhere that does exactly the same thing for your ajax stuff).